# JSON decoding in PERL - Maintaining the original data type

Tags: json, perl, mongodb

I am writing a simple perl script to read JSON from a file and insert into MongoDB. But I am facing issues with json decoding.
All non-string values in my original json are getting converted to object type after `decode_json`.

Input JSON(only part of it since it's original is huge) -

```
{
   "_id": 2006010100000801089, 
   "show_image" : false,
   "event" : "publish",
   "publish_date" :1136091600,
   "data_version" : 1
}
```

JSON that gets inserted to MongoDB -

```
{
   "_id": NumberLong("2006010100000801089"), 
   "show_image" : BinData(0,"MA=="),
   "event" : "publish",
   "publish_date" :NumberLong(1136091600),
   "data_version" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

I am providing the custom `_id` for the documents, which I want to get converted to `NumberLong` type. That is working as expected as you can see from the JSON above. But notice how other non-string values for `show_image`, `publish_date` and `data_version` got converted to it's object representation.
Is there any way I can retain the original type for these values?

Perl code snipper that does the insert -

```
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;
use JSON;
use JSON::XS
while(my $record = <$source_file>) {
  my $record_decoded = decode_json($record);
  $db_collection->insert($record_decoded);
}
```

Perl version used v5.18.2.

I looked up [JSON::XS docs](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm) but couldn't find a way to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I am very new to perl. Sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Re "JSON that gets inserted to MongoDB", That's not [JSON](http://json.org/).

Comment: Re "Is there any way I can retain the original type for these values?", I'm not sure what it is you're asking. I think you want to change what gets inserted into the database. If so, what exactly do you want inserted for your example?

Comment: e.g. Referring to my sample JSON, I want value of `show_image` to be inserted as `false` instead of `BinData(0,"MA==")` and `publish_date` to be inserted as `1136091600` instead of `NumberLong(1136091600)`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my question @ikegami. If I don't decode the JSON, I get the exception `not a reference at /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/MongoDB/Collection.pm line 235`

Comment: So that method can't be used to insert JSON, then. Why do you say you want JSON? Or why do you pass JSON to a method that doesn't accept JSON? You're not making sense.

Comment: I couldn't insert it as it is. Hence I decode it in an attempt to insert it and ran into issues I mentioned in my original question. Now I am looking for a solution so that I can insert it successfully, using the same approach or a different approach. Makes sense?

Comment: Nope. What's "it", what's "it", and what's "it"? Your comment is just as unclear as the question you have yet to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am providing the custom _id for the documents, which I want to get converted to NumberLong type. That is working as expected as you can see from the JSON above. But notice how other non-string values for show_image, publish_date and data_version got converted to it's object representation.

From your example all of the data types are actually matching aside from the boolean value for `show_image` which is currently being converted to binary data.

It is expected that numeric types are displayed as `NumberLong` or `NumberInt` when queried from the `mongo` shell. The `mongo` shell uses JavaScript, which only has a [single numeric type](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) of `Number` (64-bit floating point). Shell helpers like `NumberLong()` and `NumberInt()` are used to represent values in MongoDB's [BSON data types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) that do not have a native JavaScript equivalent.

> Referring to my sample JSON, I want value of show_image to be inserted as false instead of BinData(0,"MA==") and publish_date to be inserted as 1136091600 instead of NumberLong(1136091600)

While it's OK to insert `publish_date` as a Unixtime if that suits your use case, you may find it more useful to use MongoDB's [`Date` type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#date) instead. There are convenience methods for querying dates including [Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). FYI, date fields will be displayed in the `mongo` shell with an `ISODate()` wrapper.

The boolean value for `show_image` definitely needs an assist, though.

If you use `Data::Dumper` to inspect the result from `decode_json()`, you will see that the `show_image` field is a blessed object:

```
'show_image' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )
```

In order to get the expected `boolean` value in MongoDB, the recommended approach in the MongoDB module docs is to use the `boolean` module (see: [MongoDB::DataTypes](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/DataTypes.pod#Booleans)).

I couldn't find an obvious built-in option for JSON or JSON::XS to support serialising booleans to something other than the JSON emulated boolean class, but one solution would be to use the `Data::Clean::Base` module which is part of the [`Data::Clean::JSON`](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Clean-JSON) distribution.

Sample snippet (excluding the MongoDB set up):

```
use Data::Clean::Base;
use boolean;

my $cleanser = Data::Clean::Base->new(
    'JSON::XS::Boolean' => ['call_func', 'boolean::boolean'],
    'JSON::PP::Boolean' => ['call_func', 'boolean::boolean']
);

while (my $record = <$source_file>) {
    my $record_decoded = decode_json($record);
    $cleanser->clean_in_place($record_decoded);
    $db_collection->insert($record_decoded);
}
```

Sample record as saved in MongoDB 3.0.2:

```
{
  "_id": NumberLong("2006010100000801089"),
  "event": "publish",
  "data_version": NumberLong("1"),
  "show_image": false,
  "publish_date": NumberLong("1136091600")
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for me. Thanks so much for the detailed and awesome explanation. The NumberLong makes sense, I can live with that. But the boolean was really bothering me. I need to load millions of archive records and don't want to take any risk. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

JSON data contains only (double-precision) numbers, strings, and the special values *true*, *false*, and *null*. They can be arranged in arrays or "objects" (hashes).

The `MongoDB` engine is converting these basic types into something more complex, but the original values are available in the hash referred to by `$record_decoded`, like so

```
$record_decoded->{_id}
$record_decoded->{show_image}
$record_decoded->{event}
$record_decoded->{publish_date}
$record_decoded->{data_version}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: e.g. Referring to my sample JSON, I want value of `show_image` to be inserted as `false` instead of `BinData(0,"MA==")` and `publish_date` to be inserted as `1136091600` instead of `NumberLong(1136091600)`. I don't think this is MongoDB converting since when I insert the same JSON directly by doing a mongoimport, everything is good. i.e.  value of `show_image` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The [object serialization](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm#OBJECT_SERIALISATION) documentation (particularly `allow_tags`) in JSON::XS may do something like what you want. Note, though, that this is not a standard JSON feature and will only work with JSON::XS.